# requestRecordPermission does nothing

Tags: ios, permissions, ios7, record, avaudiosession

Since the update of iOS 7 there has been some changes with recording applications.
I have an app that used to work with iOS 5 and 6, but when I tried to run it on iOS 7 -  recording didn't respond.

I checked the internet and saw there's a new method that needs to be called.
I tried to place this code in viewDidAppear:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    if([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)])
    {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
            NSLog(@"permission : %d", granted);
        }];
    }
}
```

'granted' is always 1 although I didn't grant any permission nor saw any request popup.

Btw I'm trying to handle this using xcode 4.6.3. I made a category for AVAudioSession with requestRecordPermission method, since this method is available in iOS 7 only.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Yogesh Maheshwari's answer is more correct and should be set as the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while testing on iOS7 simulator, it looks like requestRecordPermission does not work in simulator and "granted" is always returned YES. You have to test it on a real device.

If you have tested it once on a device and responded to the permission popup then permission popup will not come again until a reset of location & privacy is done.

To reset Location & Privacy follow these steps

```
Go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy and then press "Reset Warnings" when asked.
```

Answer (score 10):

Once you gave Audio permission to the application. Your app will not show permission prompt again.

If you want to test it, change bundle ID of your app & try.

Answer (score 2):

same for iOS 8 Simulator. `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission` always returns true.On the other hand when you call

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

to open settings of your application on the simulator, microphone is never listed there.That would need to be tested on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

Add Privacy - Microphone Usage Description in your info plist to give access for the app to ask for permissions. This was causing me Thread13: signal SIGABRT error.
After this is done the error is solved automatically.

Comment: Try showing the code for your suggestion, to provide for a better quality answer.