# UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable(type) always true

Tags: ios, permissions, camera

If I block the camera via the settings App, this function always returns true. It completely ignores permissions. Anybody else noticed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: cameraMediaType)` for authorization check

```
func checkCameraAuth() {
        let authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        switch authorizationStatus{
        case .denied:
            print("you can request permission from settings")

        case .restricted:
            print("Restricted")
        case .authorized:
            print("Authorized, proceed")
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { success in
                if success {
                    print("Permission granted you can now perform operation here")
                } else {
                    print("Permission denied")
                }
            }
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should expand your answer to help other people who have searched for this issue to better understand how to address the problem.

Comment: you are right i considered the guy already have some strong skills because he capture a scenario. but you are right should provide detail let me update answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 you can check if your camera is available this way:

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) ==  .authorized {
    //already authorized
} else {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
        if granted {
            //access allowed
        } else {
            //access denied
        }
    })
}
```

from this answer here -> [How to check if the user gave permission to use the camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27646311/1146089)