# App crashes even though I added NSCameraUsageDescription in info.plist, using iOS 10, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8

Updated to Xcode 8, I am using the camera to upload photos on my app, app crashes with following very known message:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's `Info.plist` must contain
>   an `NSCameraUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

Added the `NSCameraUsageDescription` in my `info.plist`, but I still get the crash no matter what. Cleaned the app, deleted the app, even restarted Xcode. Created a build and send it to testers, hoping it's just my phone, still crashed. Same message every time.

Did this happened to anyone? Even though they added the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key does the app still crashes with the same message? Did anyone made it work? Am I missing anything?

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>For user to take photos to upload on its profile.</string>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you are presenting a camera permission dialog.. or are you checking the user approval? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803217/presenting-camera-permission-dialog-in-ios-8

Comment: @TonyMkenu I am doing both, it was a very functional app before ios10

Comment: besides `NSCameraUsageDescription ` try to add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue on iOS 10. You have to add something like this "NSCameraUsageDescription" = "Used to scan barcodes"; to your Info.Plist.string to localize the alert description for every language.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I added the key->value pair to Info.plist but have no idea where to find Info.Plist.string, as you mentioned.