# can't hear the voice through microphone using Twilio

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

**Situation**

I use [`Twilio iOS SDK`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios) for my `iOS Voip` application.

Currently, I'm trying to call from any numbers to my Voip application developed by `Twilio iOS SDK`. The Voip application has already got call and accept it properly. However, the caller can't hear the voice from the phone which installed Voip application. I guess it's because the microphone for the Voip application is turned off, but I confirmed the voice section for the application does not appear on the settings of iOS when I reach to

> [settings -> privacy -> microphone]

**Question**

How can I make my Voip application show on the microphone settings of iOS?

Comment: Have you requested access to the microphone? Like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081753/how-do-i-request-mic-record-permission-from-user

Comment: I requested access to mictophone and was not able to access it, but I found it was my info.plist of Xcode issue later. Now I could make it work. Thank you philnash for your advice.

Comment: Sweet, glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

OP in comments:

> I requested access to microphone and was not able to access it, but I
>   found it was my `info.plist` of Xcode issue later. Now I could make it
>   work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late post. The thing was I had to add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` for my info.plist from iOS 10 and it works!
[reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)